# using sed command to split string on regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have been testing the sed command's functionality in ideone. I just want to use it to perform a regex match on a string, and then save only the portion of that string which matches back into that string variable.

Here is what I have so far:

```
my $command_return = '123 test.txt';
$command_return =~ s/'\s.*'//g;
print $command_return;
```

In the real world, I will be using this to parse the results of a Linux system command. For testing, I just want to parse the string which you see above.

Comment: this `s/\s.*//g;` also does not work, am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Works for me - outputs `123` when you run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the trick with regex in general and perl in specific is being able to capture pieces of a regex.

So in your example:

```
my $command_output = "1243 test.txt"; 
my ( $command_code ) = ( $command_output =~ m/^(\d+)/ );
print $command_code,"\n";
```

This will 'capture' "one or more digits" and insert it into `$command_code`.

This works quite nicely for parsing `STDIN` because you can read it via a while loop:

```
while ( <STDIN> ) {
   my ( $command_code ) = m/^(\d+)/;
   print $command_code,"\n"; 
}
```

When you capture with a regex - using brackets - it returns an array. We cheat a little, and assign the *first* element of that array to `$command_code` and discard anything else. Because there's only one match, that's fine. But you could capture more, if you wanted.

*by default* if no 'match target' is specified, `perl` uses the implicit variable `$_` in the match - which is assigned to 'the current line' in this `while` construct.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was ideone. I created a simple perl script on my windows machine and ran it through Cygwin. It works great.

Here is what I finished with:

```
my $command_return = '123 test.txt';
print "the string to run sed command on: $command_return";
$command_return =~ s/\s.*//g;
print "\n$command_return";
```